# URL regex passed by regex buddy but failed by Dart

Tags: javascript, regex, perl, dart

I have the following regex in JavaScript regex

```regex
(https?|ftp)://([-A-Z0-9.]+)(/[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(\?[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:‌​,.;]*)?
```

It attempts to validate and empty space/s or a URL.

Yet when I attempt to use it in Dart [RegExp](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.RegExp#id_pattern)

that uses a Perle flavour regex, it does not validates.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it does not validates. share some inputs.

Comment: I'd say it does not match a URL but an e-mail address. And it's a pretty bad regex for that, as it will not support any of the new gTLDs (and without an `i` modifier, it will not match existing ccTLDs. Also I fail to understand the purpose of a regex that matches either strictly only spaces, or any text that contains an e-mail address somewhere in it (due to the use of the enclosing `\b`s.

Comment: The Dart site you linked says *"Dart regular expressions have the same syntax and semantics as JavaScript regular expressions"* so you shouldn't need to make any changes. A regex pattern is just a string in JavaScript so you may need to look at how you have defined it

Comment: A major mistake by me - I pasted the incorrect regex. What is above is for an email. The URL reqex I have is `(https?|ftp)://([-A-Z0-9.]+)(/[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(\?[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?` and [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) validates it as correct against all of the following URLs using JavaScrpt regex and Perle | http://www.regexbuddy.com
http://www.regexbuddy.com/
http://www.regexbuddy.com/index.html
http://www.regexbuddy.com/index.html?source=library
You can download RegexBuddy at http://www.regexbuddy.com/download.html.

Comment: Can you please add the full code how you use the regex in Dart?

Comment: @st_clair_clarke you should have changed your question instead of adding the correct regex as comment!

Comment: The dart2js version falls back to using JavaScript Regexps. Please try your reg-exp on Dartium and dart2js. If they behave the same, it's probably the way you define the Regexp (for example not using the "r" for the raw strings).

Answer (score 7):

Your pattern doesn't look for lowercase characters. Either you add `a-z` to the respective character groups or you use `caseSenstivie: false` as shown in the code.

```dart
var urlPattern = r"(https?|ftp)://([-A-Z0-9.]+)(/[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(\?[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:‌​,.;]*)?";
var result = new RegExp(urlPattern, caseSensitive: false).firstMatch('https://www.google.com');
```

If the result is != null a match was found.

Your pattern doesn't find `http:` URLs (only `https` or `ftp`) neither `www.google.com`.
Your statement about 'empty space' might apply to your email regexp you had in your question originally but not to your URL regexp you added in your comment.